# Change the coltypes based on a substring in colnames

Tags: r, dataframe, read.csv, column-types

I have a very large data frame of sales data (df8). When loading in, some of the variables that I want to be numeric loaded as chr. I want to change every column where the colname contains the word "Order" from chr to numeric. How can I do this?

Comment: Perhaps `?as.numeric` would be useful.

Comment: How many columns do you have?

Comment: Find out why they are imported as characters (or most likely as factors). There might be `NA` strings you should specify for import or there might be typos or unusual formats or important comments in the data column or ...

Comment: Do you know `read.csv(... colClasses)`? You can ensure they get read in as numerics the first time. Also prevents leaking lots of memory due to the `stringsAsFactors` behavior, integers are bad enough, but worse for floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use function `grepl` to find the occurrences of "order" and go through each column and convert to numeric. Notice that the variables are actually characters and it won't work if your data is a factor (that will need (`as.numeric(as.character(x))`).

```
# create data.frame with characters
xy <- data.frame(a = runif(5), b.order = runif(5), cOrder = runif(5))
xy[, c(2, 3)] <- sapply(xy[, c(2, 3)], FUN = as.character)
str(xy)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a      : num  0.914 0.468 0.106 0.624 0.841
 $ b.order: chr  "0.363523897947744" "0.56488766730763" "0.42081760126166" "0.560672372812405" ...
 $ cOrder : chr  "0.949268750846386" "0.596737345447764" "0.368769273394719" "0.717566329054534" ...

with.order <- grepl("order", names(xy), ignore.case = TRUE)

xy[, with.order] <- sapply(xy[, with.order], FUN = as.numeric)
str(xy)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a      : num  0.914 0.468 0.106 0.624 0.841
 $ b.order: num  0.364 0.565 0.421 0.561 0.768
 $ cOrder : num  0.949 0.597 0.369 0.718 0.417
```

Comment: Note that this cures the symptom, which we know from real life is often not the best course of action.

Comment: @smci That also doesn't investigate why they don't get the expected classes.

Comment: No, `read.csv()` doesn't magically infer what each column-type should be. It's very stupid and you just have to tell it with `colClasses`. In particular, as per my comment above the double-whammy of `stringsAsFactors=T` on a float gives lots of stringized floats and leaks memory like crazy.

Comment: @smci `read.table` uses `type.convert`, which does quite well with recognizing well formated numeric data. Parsing data that is not well formated is not a trivial task and that can be neither solved with `as.numeric` nor with specifying `colClasses`.

Comment: We don't know for sure the data is not well-formatted.

Comment: The data is not well formatted and there are about 99 different variables which is why I did not want to tell it all of the colclasses when reading in the csv. Most of them read in correctly but there are few instances hidden all over where letters got into the numeric columns when someone was transposing the data.The fix with grep worked well for what I am trying to do, as I would rather introduce NAs by coercion than have to go through thousands of rows to find where someone accidentally put in a letter.